Why does my JAX-based image processing loop slow down over time and how can I optimize GPU memory usage?
I'm working on an image processing task using JAX, and I've encountered an issue where the performance of my loop degrades significantly over time. Specifically, the first few iterations run quickly, but subsequent iterations slow down considerably. Additionally, I've noticed that GPU memory usage remains high throughout the process.
Here is a simplified version of my code:
@jax.jit
def raybyray(VoxelSpacing, VoxelNum, DV, P_camera, P_image, offset):
    # Function implementation
    pass

@jax.jit
def image_process(VoxelSpacing, VoxelNum, DV, P_camera, P_image, offset):
    # Function implementation
    pass

for i in range(10):
    %time drr_image = image_process(raybyray(VoxelSpacing, VoxelNum, DV, P_camera, P_image, offset))

CPU times: user 2.15 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 2.15 ms
Wall time: 1.74 ms
CPU times: user 706 µs, sys: 0 ns, total: 706 µs
Wall time: 718 µs
CPU times: user 933 µs, sys: 0 ns, total: 933 µs
Wall time: 814 µs
CPU times: user 3.88 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 3.88 ms
Wall time: 462 ms
CPU times: user 2.27 ms, sys: 1.03 ms, total: 3.31 ms
Wall time: 375 ms
CPU times: user 4.8 ms, sys: 66 µs, total: 4.86 ms
Wall time: 376 ms
CPU times: user 4.01 ms, sys: 87 µs, total: 4.1 ms
Wall time: 392 ms
CPU times: user 4.77 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 4.77 ms
Wall time: 380 ms
CPU times: user 2.56 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 2.56 ms
Wall time: 377 ms
CPU times: user 5.81 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 5.81 ms
Wall time: 391 ms

I suspect that there might be a GPU memory leak or inefficient memory management causing the slowdown. I've tried using gc.collect(), but the issue persists.
Questions:
What could be causing the performance degradation in my loop?
How can I optimize GPU memory usage to prevent this slowdown?
Are there any best practices for managing GPU memory in JAX to avoid such issues?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

[mre] required. -- the varying SI prefixes make this less obvious to spot: Wall time jumps from milliseconds to hundreds of milliseconds. CPU times seem to be stable though.

I suspect you're being misled by JAX's asynchronous dispatch: for the first few iterations, you're not measuring runtime, but rather dispatch time. Then the dispatch queue fills up, and your final few iterations are effectively measuring the actual runtime of previous iterations, which must complete before the new call can be enqueued.
To fix this, you can wrap the outputs with jax.block_until_ready():
for i in range(10):
    %time drr_image = jax.block_until_ready(
        image_process(raybyray(VoxelSpacing, VoxelNum, DV, P_camera, P_image, offset)))

For more information on things you should keep in mind for effective JAX microbenchmarks, see JAX FAQ: Benchmarking JAX code.
